# How to back from third activity to second activity in android?

Tags: android

I have 3 activity called A, B and C. I want to call A => B => C => B => A. 
When i back to B from C, app is stopped.
Please give me solution for this case. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you overriding `onbackPressed()` ?

Comment: when u go on c using intent then don't finish the activity

Comment: please share your crash log...

Comment: did you use finish() method ? if yes than show us in which activity you use

Comment: post your logcat!

Answer (score 0):

make sure when you start an activity without flag

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Bclass.this,Cclass.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

then, just use onBackPressed method for every activity..

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed()
{
     super.onBackPressed();
     //finish();
}
```

Comment: In Activity A



Although use onBackPressed method for every activity, app is stopped.

Answer (score 0):

Use following to code Start New Activity

```
StartActivity(new Intent(context, ActivityA.class));
```

This way start your activity A, B and C. And simply press back button to navigate back.

Answer (score 0):

when you start activity c from b then here don't call finish() method. only start activity and in the activity c override onBackPress()

```
    Intent inten = new Intent(B.this, C.class);
    startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use **finsh()** method in any activity than remove that method

> finsh() - finish method is totaly remove your activity from back stack
>   as when you press back button there is no any activity present in back
>   stack so application is closed

Answer (score 0):

A=>B

```
Intent intentB = new Intent(A.this, B.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

B=>C

```
Intent intentC = new Intent(B.this, C.class);
startActivity(intent);
```